# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab doubles the image size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have the following code in `background.ts`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  let targetId: number | undefined | null = null
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function (imageUrl) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {
      if (tabId !== targetId || changedProps.status != 'complete') return

      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener)

      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(imageUrl)
    })
  })

  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'popup.html' }, function (tab) {
    targetId = tab.id
  })
})
```

And I listen to the message like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import useImage from 'use-image'

export const SiteImage = observer(() => {
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState('')
    const [img] = useImage(imageUrl)
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((url) => {
            setImageUrl(url)
            const newImg = new Image()
            newImg.src = url
            newImg.onload = () => {
                console.log(newImg.naturalWidth, newImg.naturalHeight)
            }
        })
    }, [])

    return null
})
```

When I log it to the console, I get `2880 1592`, however my screen resolution is half of it `1440 796`.

How do I get an image according to my screen resolution rather than double of it?

Comment: It's either a bug or your display has double density (like Retina). Check https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's definitely double retina `Built-in Retina Display` so how do I fix it? i mean do I need to `/2` on Retina (if so, then how to check if something is Retina or not) or do I have to just use the image's width & height as my use-case is putting the image in a frame which will use image's width & height.